# Detect foreign key validity without enable it

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, foreign-keys, constraints

I need a way to check if a constraint is valid or not, but I need not to enable it. I need to know if constraints are ok/wrong before enabling them.

If I use the usual code, at the same time I enable it:

```
alter table ATEST_B with check check constraint all
```

Otherwise if I use the nocheck clause, constraints are not checked:

```
alter table ATEST_B with check nocheck constraint all
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your actual table with dummy table and check your Constraint. If its ok then drop dummy table and constraint. Apply the same on the actual table.

```
   SELECT * INTO A_DUMMY FROM ATEST_B
```

Comment: Badly, I have tables of 10-100 millions rows.

Comment: Then its not suitable, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Run a query that tests for the data that would violate the constraint you want to check.

Answer (score 0):

Looking forward I found DBCC command:

```
DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS ('fk_name')
```

The command returns all values that not respect the foreign key.It's a bit much detailed and I don't get yes/no answer, but it works fine.